# Why Cognos Metric studio is missing from IBM Cognos-10?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am using IBM Cognos 10 trial version and I am new to it. Here I created different types of reports. Recently I came to know that we can also create scorecard and strategy maps using Cognos Metric studio. Till now I just used Cognos Report studio and Cognos Framework manager. I have googled about how to open Cognos Metric studio but in every article I found that in Cognos Welcome page we can find the Metric studio, but in my Cognos welcome page there is no such kind of thing. See the following diagram.

[image]

I want to know how we can open Cognos Metric studio in IBM Cognos 10 trial version?

I have some doubts here, Is Cognos trial version they don't provide any Metric studio or we have to download it and configure it to the Cognos separately.
                                 Or
Is the installation process which I followed is Wrong?

My another doubt is, Cognos Framework manager rpd file is enough to Scorecard type of things or we have to use Metric designer for this, anyhow I did not have Metric designer as well......

Can we do all things which we can do in Cognos Metric studio also using Report studio, if yes can anyone suggest me how to do scorecards in Cognos Report studio.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about trial version, but normal Metric Studio is a separate distribution.

Comment: So we have to install it and have to configure it to cognos separately?

Comment: Just install it over existing Cognos BI installation. It would be added to Cognos Connection portal.

Answer (score 0):

There may be possibly two reasons for it that I know;

1. The Profile assigned to your User ID may not contain these
   rights/permissions.
2. Can you login using Internet Explorer or Mozilla instead and see if it appears ? Sometimes the latest versions of Browser do not render due to some bugs in Cognos Connection code.